# Override parent css settings using child gives unknown property name

Tags: html, css, django

I'm trying to override the parent settings of a dropdown menu using a child class in CSS. Unfortunately, when I try to do this it gives me an "unknown property name" error on the child class, even though I use the exact same property on the parent class.

The CSS code looks like:

```
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 160;
  min-heigth: 100;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  left:20%;
}

.test {
    min-width: 1080;
    min-heigth: 480;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

And the HTML code (django template format) looks like:

```
{% for info in infos %}
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#">dropdown item</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            {% if info.2 == "img" %}
                <!-- display image -->
            {% elif info.2 == "gif" %}
                <div class="test">Gifs and Videos are disabled for preview.</div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

In which `info.2` will always contain either the string "gif" or "img". I have not yet implemented the image yet.

However, if I use inspect element I get the following error:

[image: CSS error]

Which does not make any sense to me, as the css within the `dropdown-content` class does correctly work. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because 1080 can be 1080 potatoes or elephants, You need to specifiy `px` or whatever unit you prefer

Comment: Glad to hear it helped